# Can I use the URLTrigger plugin for FogBugz with TestRail?

Tags: fogbugz

We're using [TestRail](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/) and FogBugz.  I found this trigger today:

http://help.fogcreek.com/7755

> The URL Trigger Plugin allows you to specify an HTTP request to be
>   sent to a specific URL when events occur in FogBugz. To create a
>   URLTrigger, select one or more events that your trigger will respond
>   to, then add values to the URL querystring using a list of variables
>   presented by the plugin.

I'm trying to get this to integrate, somehow, with TestRail.  Ideal steps:

1. In TestRail, mark a test as failed, and enter the FB number in the Defects box.
2. In FogBugz, resolve the case.
3. FogBugz, using this plugin, sends an update string to TestRail, and changes the status of the test to "Retest".

My question: is this even possible, or am I dreaming again?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with only URLTrigger plugin.

The main issue is that TestRail has access to the FB case number but FB does not know the TestRail case numbers.  To do what you want you'll need a fuller feature set to look up the TestRail cases by "defect" (FB case) and then set their status.

It can likely be done with a custom FogBugz plugin which can include significantly more logic and multiple calls to the TestRail API.